# Using two structures in Array or ArrayList in Java

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

In C#, there was a chance to use:

```
Arraylist<String,int> data = Arraylist();
```

as far as i remember.

Is there any version of this in Java?

For example, the information on the array will be :

```
Apple 5
Tomato 3
Potato 9
... etc.
```

This is why I am trying to define such a structure.

EDITED:

How about creating a class such as;

```
public class x
{
int a;
String  b;
}
```

and creating the arraylist from this class.

```
ArrayList<x> data = new ArrayList<x>();
```

Will this work?

Comment: C# does not allow that. In fact, there's no such thing as a generic ArrayList in C#. And List<T> takes a single generic parameter.

Comment: Note: C# would be `Dictionary<string, int>`, where the strings are unique. Having a non-unique key value list is slightly less straightforward.

Comment: What exactly is your intent with this code? What's the relationship of the number to the `String`? The best thing to do here depends greatly on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other option (I'm not saying it's a better option) would be to use:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>
```

Where you have a class `Pair`:

```
class Pair<E, F> {
    public E one;
    public F two;
}
```

Comment: I often see java answers with `List<T> foo = new ArrayList<T>()` or, in this question, `Map<T, U> map = new HashMap<T, U>()`. Is `ArrayList<>` a more specialized version of `List<>` and its just a convention to declare and instantiate this way? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: @Anthony Pegram List is an interface.  ArrayList is an implementation of List.

Comment: @Anthony: it's always best to program to the most general interface that meets your requirements.  Declaring your variable as `List` or `Map` means that you can easily swap in a new implementation (say `LinkedList` or `SortedMap`) at a later time if you so desire.

Comment: @Anthony, `List<T>` is the interface and `ArrayList<T>` is the class that implements it.  It is just good practice to declare the variable as the interface.  It will allow you to change the implementation that you want to use in the future.

Comment: @Justin: Under rare cases this might be nice, but I find typically if you're going to go this route you should just make an actual class that encapsulates the two fields.

Comment: @Jonathan, Mark, thanks. I understand the principal, certainly, yet seeing *every* answer do it (might be overstating) almost makes it seem compulsory rather than simply being good practice.

Comment: I accepted Justin's solution, since this is what I really want. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are looking for a way to do  { key,value } pair then you should use a Map. Example below and check out the java docs.

```
Map<String,Integer> someMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Read more on map [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

If you are looking for a place holder to store the piece of data then you need to something like this.

```
public final class Fruit{

private String fruitName;
private Integer fruitCount;

//constructor initialized values.
//getters and setters for those
}
```

Then in your main class you define this way.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

To read up more on list read this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: Assuming you are actually trying to map a String to an integer, yes.  If the OP is just trying to correlate the two pieces of data (say each element of the list represents a container of fruit of a variable quantity) than you just need a class with a `String` and `int` member and store that instead.

Comment: Correct Mark. But from the data it looks like he is wanting a fruit name and perhaps a count of how many fruits of each type he has. However, I could be completely wrong here. If it's just a data holder then we need to create a class of fruits. I will modify my answer and add proper assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you need a `Map` instead of a `List`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Apple", 5);
map.put("Tomato", 3);
map.put("Potato", 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

What the best thing to do here is depends greatly on what the relationship between the `String` and the number are. Here are a number of possibilities and what you might want to do with them.

**The number is an ID or some such closely related property:**

Create a class to represent these objects and associate their properties.

```
public class Item {
  private final int id;
  private final String name;

  // constructor, getters, equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

**The number is a count of the named items:**

Use a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) to keep a count of the items.

```
Multiset<String> items = HashMultiset.create();
items.add("Apple", 5);
items.add("Tomato", 3);
// etc.
```

**The number is something else related to the `String` but not closely enough to store in a single object:**

Use a normal `Map` as suggested in other answers.

**A `Pair` is not a great solution**

While you've accepted an answer suggesting the use of a `Pair` class, I strongly recommend against that, as `Pair` does nothing to indicate what the two values it contains are *nor* what the relationship between them is and it doesn't provide the conveniences of a `Map` as far as getting the value that's associated with a particular key either.